# VBA error 'Cannot change part of a merged cell'

Tags: excel, vba

Having a problem with the VBA error "Cannot change part of a merged cell"

Here is my code. It clears the range on the first sheet, then hides the Raw Samples sheet. The loop then clears the ranges on the unhidden sheets in the workbook because they are formatted the exact same. This code only works if I go into all the sheets and clear any formatting for merged cells. I need this code to run on a number of workbooks so having to do this would be very time consuming or I'd have to add code to clear users formats before clearing ranges.

```
sheets("Raw Samples").select
Range("A9:AB3000").select
selection.clearcontents
activewindow.selectedsheets.visible = False

dim ws as worksheet
for each ws in activeworkbook.worksheets
ws.range("B3:G342").clearContents
next ws

activeworkbook.sheets("Raw Samples").visible = true
```

My questions are

1. Does a for next loop still check for formatting on a hidden sheet?
2. Is there a way to get around having to unformat a sheet but still clear the specified ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1. Does a for next loop still check for formatting on a hidden sheet?

No it doesn't

> Q2. Is there a way to get around having to unformat a sheet but still clear the specified ranges?

Yes. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim boolHidden As Boolean

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Raw Samples" Then
            Set rng = ws.Range("B3:G342")

            If ws.Visible = False Then
                boolHidden = True
                ws.Visible = True
            End If

            Application.Goto Reference:=rng
            Selection.ClearContents

            If boolHidden = True Then
                ws.Visible = False
                boolHidden = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I input your code above and it's giving me the "Method 'goto' of object'_Application' failed. you actually write in reference:=rng right? Or should that be in ().

Comment: The "Raw Samples" worksheet is hidden because I want to clear the range B3:G342 on all the other sheets open besides that one.

Comment: I have just made a change to the above code. Now try it... You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Unfortunately that clears the range B3:G342 on the "Raw Samples" worksheet as well, which is what I don't want to happen. Is there a way to run your code and to leave the Raw Samples worksheet hidden? I don't need the B3:G342 range cleared on that sheet.